# org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException when trying to Insert a NEW Parent with Child entities (@EmbeddedID)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I'm using Spring Data JPA to manage my Java Entities with DB Tables but I had some troubles  trying to insert a parent entity with its child entities in one transaction.

Basically this Child has two parents, Parent A and B, but in the transaction the ID of the parent B is known, so I just want to get the Parent A ID (generated by AUTO_INCREMENT) to assign it to the children and then merge them into DB.

Here's my code:

**ParentA.java**

```java
package ...
import ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_A")
public class ParentA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentA", cascadeType = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> children;

    // ...getters and setters, hashcode and toString

}
```

**ParentB.java**

```java
package ...
import ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_B")
public class ParentB implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentB")
    private Set<Child> children;

    // ...getters and setters, hashcode and toString

}
```

**ChildPK.java**

```java
package ...
import ...

@Embeddable
public class ChildPK implements Serializable {
    
    private Long parentAId;
    
    private Long parentBId;

    // ... constructor, getters and setters, hashcode and toString
}
```

**Child.java**

```java
package ...
import ...

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildPK id;

    @MapsId("parentAId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private ParentA parentA;
    
    @MapsId("parentBId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_B_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private ParentB parentB;

    // ... getters and setters, hashcode and toString
}
```

**The stack trace is:**

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.example.demo.domain.Child.parentA]
        at org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Component$ValueGenerationPlan.execute(Component.java:509)
        at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:744)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:712)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
        ... omitted
```

When I execute the `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save` method to UPDATE the parent and children it works fine, the problem is when I try to insert a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the fields in `ChildPK` are the source for insert/update so if these values are null or you forget to change them, you will run into trouble. Setting just `Child.parentA` and `Child.parentB` is not enough or actually even unnecessary I believe. It should be fine to set just the id values in `ChildPK`